# Should I use the Log-Likelihood (G2) test to compare word frequency across corpora?

Tags: corpora, methodology

I need to compare the frequency of occurrence of a word in two corpora.

Take for example the word fail which occurs 311 times in a  corpus containing language from the sciences (2 million tokens) and 420 times in a corpus containing language from the arts (2.2 million tokens).

Many textbooks recommend the LL test for such a task. However my understanding is that: 
1) the LL test assumes parametric distribution 
2) that my data is not normally distributed
Therefore the LL test would not be suitable for this purpose.  Is this correct?

Thanks in advance